# How to building training tools for tesseract3.04 on windows platform?

Tags: windows, libraries, tesseract, training-data

I am compiling the tesseract 3.04 from source on windows 8 and have compiled it successfully,not including training tool. 
To build training tool,I spend a lot of time to search those additional libraries but can not find their windows vertions. 
These libraries are :
libicu-dev, libpango1.0-dev, libcairo2-dev.
(https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract)

Who has done it? How to build it on windows platform? 
Thank you very much at advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's one Windows distro provided by UB Mannheim.

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Comment: Thank you for your url !   I can download it. It is version 3.05 and there is not other versions. That will be better if  it is version 3.04.